# Maintance Mode: How to show the content of my 503.phtml page istead of exceptions

Tags: magento2, production-mode, maintenance, 503

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Unable to proceed: the maintenance mode is enabled. 

Exception #0 (Exception): Unable to proceed: the maintenance mode is enabled. 
<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at [pub/index.php:31]
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your content in this file :

```
pub/errors/default/503.phtml
```

Will show your content instead of the above message and enable the Production mode.

If you need any help please let me know.

Comment: Thanks für your Help. Do you happen to know if it's possible to view the content of 503.phtml without enabling the Production mode?

Comment: No, because the maintenance page is always enabled in the production mode. If this answer helps you please mark this as an answer so it may help others.

Answer (score 0):

It's the default behavior in Magento when enabling the maintenance mode in the **Developer** mode.
If you switch to **production** or **default** mode, you can see the normal maintenance page content.

Comment: Thanks für your Help. Do you happen to know if it's possible to view the content of 503.phtml without enabling the Production mode?

Comment: @AbdullahOrabi You can access the **503.php** to see the content of **503.phtml** file (it also works when the site is disabled maintenance mode): `<your site domain>/errors/503.php`. Eg, https://magento.test/errors/503.php